# Install Ubuntu error on virtual box

Tags: ubuntu, installation, virtualbox

pc: windows 10, 64bit

installing Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 32bit from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
(there is no 64bit ubuntu in VirtualBox 5)

at the very first start, result is this.

end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exit code=0x00000004
[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/904yA.png)

what is happening? is there any solution?

I used ubuntu on VM last year.
I think the followings are differences...

1. windows (8.1 -> 10)
2. virtualbox version (4.3? -> 5)

is this error related with these two?

Comment: I do not know why but ubuntu install succeeded after rebooted my pc

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you load your iso onto a freshly formatted USB drive --and-- make sure you wait for the first ever boot of ubuntu to finish; don't assume it's crashed and reboot, even if it takes a stupidly long time.

Comment: Thank you, need to be cautious about that.

Comment: I solved my problem but it's not because of your comment. as I mentioned, I rebooted my pc and the error was gone.

Comment: glad to know your problem is fixed:)